# Setting default layout product detail page

Tags: layout, product-list, ce-1.9.2.2

I'm customizing the layout in CE-1.9.2.2.
After selecting a product in the grid, I get to the productdetails.
This page is shown in 1column-layout.
I want to use the 3column-layout in this view.

I know I can change the view for each product seperately, but I wan't it to be changed for all and as default.

Where do I look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the fastest way is redifine the root template for those routes in a local.xml:

> [root]/app/design/frontend/{your_package}/{your_theme}/layout/local.xml

Then apply this:

```
<reference name="root">
    <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/{your_template}.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

to all "product-list" related routes, these are:

```
<catalog_category_default/> 
<catalog_category_layered/>
<catalogsearch_result_index/>
<catalogsearch_advanced_result/>
```

for "product-view"

```
<catalog_product_view/>
```

So for the **catalog_product_view** route the complete code would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="root">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/{your_template}.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>

    ... other routes ...

</layout>
```

Comment: I created : [root]/app/design/frontend/outletdrogist/default/layout/local.xml with `<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate"><template>page/3columns.phtml</template></action>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>` and that for the 3 other routes.
Cache is disabled, but yet gives https://outletdrogist.nl/staging/eyelove-brillenkoker.html/ 1 column.
https://outletdrogist.nl/staging/nieuw/elmex-sensetive-professional-tandspoeling-zonder-alcohol.html is set by hand and in 3 columns.

Comment: if local.xml did not exist yet, you need to add also `<?xml version="1.0"?><layout>` at the beginning and `</layout>` at the end

Comment: @fschmengler tnxs i'll update my answer.

Comment: I think I'm still missing something here. I added the xml and layout-tags, but still 1 column. I don't have to whitelist local.xml or something like that? Or do I need another route like `<catalog_product_view>`?

Comment: Right! your link point to a catalog_product_view not a product grid.  you just need to change the root template for: `<catalog_product_view>` route

Comment: i've updated the answer, take a look!

Comment: It's working. Thank you (both) very much.
Also handy http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_validator.asp .
I found a mistake on my last test and after the check + fix it worked.